# In Active Admin / Arbre form, how I can put HTML (specifically a line break) in a label?

Tags: activeadmin, formtastic, arbre

This is a little unorthodox, but I don't think it should be difficult.

I have a Active Admin form:

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors(*f.object.errors.keys)
  f.inputs do
    f.input :email
    f.input :name

    # read-only field that still matches formatting of form
    li do
      label "Last Update Time<br/>(except password changes)"
      div f.object.last_update_time
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

When rendered, the `last_update_time` label does not convert the `<br/>` into a line break.  Similarly, html entity codes such as `&copy;` (the copyright `(c)`) aren't converted either.

How can I get html to render in that label?

Stuff I tried that doesn't work:

- `label "foo<br/>bar".html_safe`
- `label raw("foo<br/>bar")`
- a block like this (gets an error on `label`: "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..3)"):

  ```
    label do
      "foo"
      br
      "bar"
    end
  ```

Anybody know the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try next:

```
li do
  text_node "<label>Last Update Time<br/>(except password changes)"</label>".html_safe
  div f.object.last_update_time 
end
```

`&copy;` must be inside a text_node too like:

```
text_node "&copy;".html_safe
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Well, a perfect _workaround_, anyway.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alas Formtastic is not built on Arbre and is somewhat hacked into ActiveAdmin.  I would try replacing Formtastic's `label` here with Arbre's [text_node](https://activeadmin.info/12-arbre-components.html#text-node)

Comment: But I actually want a `<label>` tag, so it will have the AA label styles.  (I could use something else, and then adjust my css for it to duplicate the AA label styles, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.)